# Modificar tamaño en porcentaje de slider revolution

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

estoy desesperado y necesito cualquier ayuda u opinion que puedan darme.
Utilizo plugin de revolution slider en wordpress, sin embargo el plugin da configuración en pixeles a lo cual yo necesito que el plugin se visualice en 3/4 de pantalla (75%), como puedo lograr esto?
*Nota: el plugin es responsive y la plantilla es uncode child*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oye pues la verdad la solución es muy sencilla, si usas wpbakery visual composer o cualquier otro editor visual para editar las paginas, solo debes:

**crear una fila con dos columnas una de 75% y otra de 25% hablando técnicamente seria una de 3/4 y otra de 1/4**

esto de seguro solucionaría tu  problema.

Comment: Eso lo soluciona, sin embargo yo el slider lo uso en la sección de la plantilla "header" por lo cual no puedo modificar el tamaño